# SSIS Execute SQL task vs stored procedure (performance)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssis

At this time I have one server with a few databases. I have to move Transact-SQL jobs to SSIS packages (company's policy, so I have to do it).

The advantage of the T-SQL is that I can identify really fast if we have modifications (`msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps`). If I moved the scripts to SSIS Execute SQL tasks, it will be really hard.

I read a lot of post about this topic, but I didn't find the answer.

If I put the scripts into stored procedures and use it in Data Flow tasks, will I lose performance? If yes, do you have any idea how do I search quickly in SSIS packages without opening those?

Comment: You said: "I can identify really fast if we have modifications", by saying that your performance is related to your being able to make changes and NOT to the script execution time. If so please amend your question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

> f I put the scripts into stored procedures and use it in Data Flow tasks, will I lose performance?

Shouldn't.  And dynamic SQL in stored procedures will be identical to a TSQL job step.

> If yes, do you have any idea how do I search quickly in SSIS packages without opening those?

SSIS packages are XML files.  And SSIS projects can be easily managed in a source control system with Visual Studio.  This really is a better way.

Comment: So if I have 1000 SSIS packages, then I can't search in those without opening. The first part is okay, understand it. Thanks!

Comment: You would have one package per job, with one Execute SQL Task per job step, grouped into one or a handful of SSIS projects.  All the packages are XML files sitting on your disk.  You can search them.  Also if you put them in a repo like GitHub or Azure Dev Ops Git you can search them online.

Comment: We have Azure. Didn't use Azure dev ops git before, but I will check it tomorrow. Thanks for that too :)

Comment: Great. Download Visual Studio Communinty edition https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/, install the SSIS add-in https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects.  And work through some tutorials here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/integration-services-tutorials?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: A SPROC called in an TSQL Job Step should have the same performance was one called from an ExecuteSQL Task in SSIS.

In general, the reason you'd do it all in SSIS is that you then have a single, unified set of error handling inside the package.  Also, any control flow is more intuitive to set up in SSIS rather than having job steps which could jump around like an old BASIC program depending step outcome. 

You also don't put SPROCs in Data Flow Tasks unless it is a data source for the flow.  They're usually Control Flow items which execute a self contained item of work.